# Kotlin class that implements Java interface is using default method implementations, rather than overrides

Tags: java, kotlin

Lets have interface in Java:

```java
public interface Currency {
   default String getName() {
       throw new NotImplementedException("Implement it!");
   }
}
```

Now I want create an implementation of this interface in Kotlin:

```kotlin
object Dollar : Currency {
     val name = "$"

     override fun getName() {
          return name
     }
}
```

If I initialize `Dollar` class by `Dollar()` and then call `.getName()` on it, I am getting `NotImplementedException` exception.

Why is that? I cannot combine Java interfaces with Kotlin implementations?

Comment: It's a bug in Kotlin - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18324 It's still open after so many years.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code

```
object Dollar : Currency {
     val name = "$"

     override fun getName(): String {
          return name
     }
}
```

Produces this error

```
Dollar.kt:2:6: error: platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getName()Ljava/lang/String;):
    fun <get-name>(): String defined in Dollar
    fun getName(): String defined in Dollar
     val name = "$"
     ^
Dollar.kt:4:6: error: platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getName()Ljava/lang/String;):
    fun <get-name>(): String defined in Dollar
    fun getName(): String defined in Dollar
     override fun getName(): String {
```

You've actually declared two functions called `getName` here as far as the JVM is concerned, you just don't know it yet. Kotlin compiles `val` declarations into both an internal (private) field and a getter function, which in your case ends up being called `getName`. Now, you can't have a property `name` override a Java method `getName`, even if they'll end up getting compiled to the same name. Kotlin considers the two distinct and the fact that they end up the same is merely an implementation detail. So simply rename your instance variable and the explicit getter will be the only candidate for override.

```
object Dollar : Currency {
     val _name = "$"

     override fun getName(): String {
          return _name
     }
}
```